# Laravel migration files

Tags: laravel

I am using `php artisan migrate` to run the migration file. But it does not creating tables in database. Then I delete "user and password reset" migration files and run the `php artisan migrate` command. Then my new migration files run successfully and create table in database.

And when I creates more migration files and run the command, again its not creating tables in database. Again to create tables I have deleted the previous made migration files which was created by me.

Please help me with this. Each time I have to delete one or more migration files to run the new migration files ?

And what is this error `Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes` ?

Comment: Please show your migration file

Comment: public function up()
    {
         Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 255)->unique();
            $table->string('title', 140);
            $table->string('description', 500);
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->integer('brand_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('created_at_ip');
            $table->string('updated_at_ip');
        });
    }

Comment: Did you find any error ?

Comment: Ok I find the error myself. I am defining string('name', 255) but in my AppServiceProvider file I defined its length 191. Now I changed the string('name', 255) to string('name', 170). Its working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of MySQL is less than 5.7 you need to set the default string length in your **AppServiceProvider**.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

This is outlined in the
[Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-indexes).

Comment: Yes, I add this in **AppServiceProvider** file. But it showing the same error.

' [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQ
  L: alter table `employees` add unique `employees_email_unique`(`email`))



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes'